# jsPlumb: No connectionDetached event when connectionMoved event fires

Tags: events, connection, move, jsplumb, detach

It seems that there is no connectionDetached event when connectionMoved event fires.

So when you move a connection, it creates a new one and keeps the old one.

I would like to remove the first connection please. Preferrably before the second one is created (not to go over maxConnections). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Simon pointed out that: "when a connection is moved jsPlumb does not create a new one and remove the old one. It just changes the elements for its endpoints."

This is how the problem was solved:

```
    jsPlumbMain.bind("connection", function (info, originalEvent ) {
    if (originalEvent == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (moving) {
        // Remove old connection from DB
        removeItem(info.connection .ourId);
    }
    currentConnection = info.connection;
    var hoverPaintStyle = {strokeStyle: "#CC3333"};
    currentConnection.setHoverPaintStyle(hoverPaintStyle);
    var src = info.sourceEndpoint;
    var dst = info.targetEndpoint;
    createConnection(src.ourId, dst.ourId);

    moving = false;
});

jsPlumbMain.bind("connectionDetached", function (info) {
    var conn = info.connection;
    removeItem(conn.ourId);
    moving = false;
});

jsPlumbMain.bind("connectionMoved", function (info, originalEvent) {
    alert('moved');
    moving = true;
});
```